# Program to tell which if any of three numbers is in the middle

Tags: c, c99

I wrote this program, and it does what it asks, but it's so big and ugly. What can I change?

Some examples:

> ```
> a  b  c --->
> 5  1  12   a is between b and c
> 5  12 1    a is between c and b
> 5  5  2    there is no gap
> ```

This was in an example of a test that is supposed to be small, so that's why I'm asking if there is another way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void){
int a,b,c;

printf("Inserir 3 números: "); //its in portuguese, insert 3 numbers
scanf("%i %i %i",&a,&b,&c);

if(a==b||b==c||a==b){
    printf("não há intervalo\n"); //there is no gap
    exit(0);
}

int maior, meio, menor,flag,flag2,flag3;

maior=a; //maior means biggest
flag=1;
if(maior<b){
    maior=b;
    flag=2;
}if(maior<c){
    flag=3;
    maior=c;
}

if(maior!=a){
    meio=a;  //meio means middle
    flag2=1;
    if(meio<b&&b<maior){
        meio=b;
        flag2=2;
    }if(meio<c&&c<maior){
        flag2=3;
    }
}else{
    meio=b;
    flag2=2;
    if(meio<c&&c<maior){
        flag2=3;
    }
}

menor=a; //menor means smallest
flag3=1;
if(menor>b){
    menor=b;
    flag3=2;
}if(menor>c){
    flag3=3;        
}

if(flag2==1)
    printf("o a entre [");
if(flag2==2)
    printf("o b entre [");
if(flag2==3)
    printf("o c entre [");

if(flag3==1)
    printf("a e ");
if(flag3==2)
    printf("b e ");
if(flag3==3)
    printf("c e ");

if(flag==1)
    printf("a]\n");
if(flag==2)
    printf("b]\n");
if(flag==3)
    printf("c]\n");


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Well, first of all, consider adopting one of the myriad common indentation-styles and use it consistently.
   Doing so will make your code far easier to read *and* write.
2. You should test whether you really got three numbers.
   Currently, you don't, which leads to UB.
3. If in doubt, sort.

   That eliminates an astonishing number of problems.
4. You aren't using anything from `<math.h>`, so don't include it.
5. `exit(0);` and `return 0;` have nearly the same effect when done in `main`.
   The only differences are when `main` is called recursively, and we won't do such an abomination outside the [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/). (Or if we change to a different language, like C++, but who would do that?)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct namednumber {int num; char name; } namednumber;

static int comp_namednumber(const void* pa, const void* pb) {
    int a = ((namednumber*)pa)->num,
        b = ((namednumber*)pb)->num;
    return (a > b) - (a < b);
}

int main() { // No need for void in the parameter-list, this is a definition
    int a, b, c;
    printf("Please enter three numbers:\n");
    if(3 != scanf("%i %i %i", &a, &b, &c)) {
        printf("You didn't enter three numbers. Aborting.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if(a == b || b == c || c == a) {
        printf("There is no gap.");
        return 0;
    }

    namednumber data[] = {{a,'a'},{b,'b'},{c,'c'}};
    qsort(data, 3, sizeof *data, comp_namednumber);
    printf("%c is between %c and %c\n", data[1].name, data[0].name, data[2].name);

    return 0; // This line is implicit in C99+
}
```

Actually, getting out `qsort` is severe overkill, so here with a standard [sorting-network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void sort2(int* a, char* na, int* b, char* nb) {
    if(*a < *b) return;
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
    char nt = *na;
    *na = *nb;
    *nb = nt;
}

int main() {
    int a, b, c;
    printf("Please enter three numbers:\n");
    if(3 != scanf("%i %i %i", &a, &b, &c)) {
        printf("You didn't enter three numbers. Aborting.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if(a == b || b == c || c == a) {
        printf("There is no gap.");
        return 0;
    }

    char na = 'a', nb = 'b', nc = 'c';
    sort2(&a, &na, &b, &nb);
    sort2(&a, &na, &c, &nc);
    sort2(&b, &nb, &c, &nc);
    printf("%c is between %c and %c\n", nb, na, nc);
}
```

Comment: Well, I don't understand about half of what you wrote, but it's surely much more better looking than mine. I'll play around with it. Thank you very much!